# Getting an object with a variable. -javascript-

Tags: javascript, object

```
var i = "test";
var test1 = {
    test: 3,
    b: 3
};
console.log(test1.i);
```

Sorry if it's a simple answer, I am still learning.

var i is looping to something different every few seconds and var i will always be something on test1.

Comment: [*Square bracket notation*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) is your answer: `console.log(test1[i])`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve a property of an object you can use the `.` notation, or the `[]` notation

```
var test1 = {
    test: 3,
    b: 3
};
```

Using `.` notation

```
test1.test;       // -> returns 3
```

Using `[]` notation

```
var propertyName = 'test'
test1[propertyName];       // -> returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
var test1 = {
    test : 3
};
console.log(test1[i])
```

Comment: Code only answers are not liked, you should add an explanation.